# BotBuilderFramwork: FAILED TO INITIALIZE - Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2017, azure-sql-database, botframework, chatbot

Base Informations:

- **Chatbot:** Chatbot with MS-Bot Framwork (v3). Accesses SQL DB in Azure
- **System:** Windows 10 (Latest update: KB4346783)
- **IDE:** Visual Studio 2017 (Updated Today)

I am trying to test a chatbot created with the MS-BotFramework, using the Bot-Framework Emulator. 
When I click in Visual Studio debug&deployed 
AND after that, press in the Bot Framework Emulator the button "start a new conversation",
the following error message appears in the output debug window:

> Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Information: 100: Role
>   environment . INITIALIZING Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime
>   Information: 100: Role environment . INITIALED RETURNED.
>   HRresult=-2147024894 Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime Error: 102
>   : Role environment . FAILED TO INITIALIZE. hr: -2147024894

Peripheral information:

- Application Insights is enabled.
- This morning both an automatic
  Windows and a Visual Studio update were performed.
- Last Friday the
  chatbot was still working fine, since there were no more changes to
  the code

the whole day I tried to resolve this bug by many "FAILED TO INITIALIZE -2147024894"-Bug Reports, but nothing hleped to fix it..

I hope someone can help me out.

Best regards,

PG

Comment: Peter, It's not clear what you're doing. Are you getting this error when you try to run and debug your bot in Visual Studio with the emulator or are you getting error when you try to deploy your bot to Azure from Visual Studio? Also, which bot framework version are you using, v3 or v4?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm using the bot framework v3. I'm getting the error when I run and debug my bot in Visual Studio AND after that, press in the Bot Framework Emulator the button "start a new conversation".

Comment: Peter, are you still experiencing an issue or has it since been resolved?

Comment: After nothing worked, I rebuilt the whole Windows system. After that the project could be built. But the error still occurs. So the bug was not fixed, but I can develop further even with the bug.